# "Load More Posts" with jQuery Masonry

Tags: jquery, append

I have implemented Masonry for a custom page template (Wordpress). I have stipulated that only the first 10 posts are shown. However, I wanted to create a "Load More" link so that the next 10 posts are shown, and so on until Masonry reaches the last post.

I'm not too knowledgeable with the append method, and how to correctly use syntax for it. 
For example, if the container is #newsContainer and each tile is .newsContainerPost, how would I correctly place this into (below)?

```
$('#append').click(function(){
  var $boxes = $( boxMaker.makeBoxes() );
  $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps you would need to take to make this happen. First you would need to use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to call your database and get the items (in this case posts). You would most likely want to return a JSON string that can be parsed to build your HTML markup for the posts. An example is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/load-more.php",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(data) {
            if(!data){
                 //possible errors
                 return false;
            }
            var posts = JSON.parse(data);
            var container = document.getElementById('container')
            for(var i in posts){
               var post = posts[i];
               //now post will have info like post.image, post.title
               //post.excerpt, and whatever else you put in the php script
               //build the post with HTML and append it to the container
               //and [reload masonry][2] eaxmple
               var div = document.createNode('div');
               var h1 = document.createNode('h1');
               h1.innerHTML = post.title;
               div.appendChild(h1);
               container.appendChild(div);
               container.masonry( 'reload' );                   
            }
        }
    });
```

Second you need your `load-more.php` to return your 10 posts as a JSON string. You will need to [run the WP loop outside of the engine](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/run-a-loop-outside-of-wordpress/).

```
<?php
    // Include WordPress
    define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
    require('/server/path/to/your/wordpress/site/htdocs/blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    query_posts('showposts=10');
    $arr = new array();
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    //put in whatever info you want from the post in a new
    //array index
    $arr[the_ID()]['title'] = the_title();
endwhile;

return json_encode(arr); 

?>
```

Place the ajax call inside a function and call that function on the event you want to load more; like clicking a button, or scrolling to the bottom of the page.

I hope this helps.